# Elementary Set Theory Cardinality of this Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i have been struggling with the following problem:

Prove if this * set has cardinality $\mathbb N, \mathcal P(\mathbb N) $ or  $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb N)) $ .

*$\mathrm X:=$ The set of all strictly increasing functions $\mathcal f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, such that $\mathcal f(0)=0$, and $\mathcal f(n) \le 2n.$

So here is my attempt:

We define a function $\phi: \mathrm X\to  \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ like this:
Let $y$ be a member of X.

$\phi(y) = \{y(1),y(2),...,y(n),...\}$
 So $\phi$ is an injection, and we can conclude that $Card (\mathrm X)\le Card( P(\mathbb N))$.

I tried using the diagonal argument to show that $X$ is not countable, but im not sure if it follows.

I would be really glad if someone could help me with this, this is not any kind of homework, im just honestly studying for my test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Define $\psi:\{1,2\}^{\Bbb N}\to X$ by 
$$\psi(u)\ :=\ n\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}u_i\,.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is a bijection, and there is also a Bijection from P(N) to the set of all functions from N to {1,2} so we conclude that the right answer is P(N), isnt it?

Comment: well, this is an injection only (e.g. no sequence starting with $(1,2,5)$ will be in the image), but yes, together with your $\phi$, it follows.